# Approach to managing decreasing set of interconnected numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, constraint-programming

We have four variables:

- `a`, which represents numbers from 0-999
- `b`, which represents `a`1000 (`b` = 3 represents `a` = 3000)
- `c`, which represents `b`1000
- `d`, which represents `c`100 (not 1000)

What is the easiest, most efficient or just the standard way of dealing with **subtraction**/addition to any of those numbers? Imagine I decrease `a` with 500, while it represents `0`, but since `b` could be `1` (hence `a` can be `1000`) I can and have to recalculate `a` and `b`.

Comment: Your last sentence is very difficult to interpret as it is currently written

Comment: Clarification for other users: `a`1000 here denotes $a \times 1000$

Comment: To the extent that I understand what you're trying to ask, it looks like this is a programming question and is better suited for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The language barrier and the lack of math skills really complicates the matter. I think it is more of a math question than it is a programming question. The problem I have is not with the programming, but with the math.

Comment: Maybe you can answer this: if you want to decrease `a` by 500, why can't you just update all values to match? That is, what's wrong with assigning $a = a - 500,$ $b = b - 0.5$, $c = c - 0.0005$, and so on?

Comment: Why in particular is subtraction more difficult than addition in your situation?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The values cannot be negative and they can only represent whole numbers in their respective range. If every variable is 0, a subtraction can not be made, but if `a` > 499 or `b` > 0 or `c` > 0 or `d` > 0 then it can, but would require recalculations in the last 3 cases. The logic is that `c` = 1 has the equal logical value of 1000000 `a`

Comment: If I use more of a "programming" approach, which was the only thing I came up with, I would have converted all variables to be decayed to `a` value, perform simple arithmetic then convert numbers back to their representations, but in programming, the temporary converted variable is too big, which was a constraint-confronting and inefficient per se.

Comment: I think I finally figured out what you are trying to do.  You have a quanties $X_1,X_2$ represented in the form 
$$
X_i = a_i + 10^3 \cdot b_i  + 10^6 \cdot c_i + 10^8 \cdot d_i
$$
for $i = 1,2$.  You would like to be able to calculate a representation for $X_1 + X_2$ or $X_1 - X_2$ using the numbers $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i$ directly.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't know, but I think you got it. Each quantity represents greater value. Like days being greatest, than hours, minutes, seconds etc. Subtrating 1 second from one day would have an impact of the entire representation. I think this is well-compared.

Comment: The only difference being that each quantity has a different value.
`b` has `a` x 1000, `c` has `b` x 1000 and `d` has `c` x 100

Comment: It seems that we understand each other now.  The method that you're trying to implement is usually referred to as "addition/subtraction with [carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic))".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, that's nice I am starting to learn important things already. Knowing the right terminology is one of the most important mandatory things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $(a,b,c,d)$ to denote the number $a + 10^3 \cdot b  + 10^6 \cdot c + 10^8 \cdot d$ (the total amount of "$a$-units").  I will assume that we have 
$$
0 \leq a \leq 999 , \quad 0 \leq b \leq 999
, \quad 0 \leq c \leq 99, \quad 0 \leq d.
$$
We can calculate the representation `(a,b,c,d)` of `(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1) + (a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2)` with the process described in the pseudocode below.

```
initialize a = b = c = d = 0
a = a + a_1 + a_2
if a > 999
    a = a - 1000
    b = 1
b = b + b_1 + b_2
if b > 999
    b = b - 1000
    c = 1
c = c + c_1 + c_2
if c > 99
    c = c - 100
    d = 1
d = d + d_1 + d_2
```

Of course, all this can be implemented with a loop if we take $a,b,c,d$ as elements of an array.

We can calculate `(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1) - (a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2)` similarly.  The first step after initializing variables would be

```
if a_2 > a_1
    a_2 = a_2 + 1000
    b_2 = b_2 - 1
a = a_2 - a_1
```

Repeat this until the last step:

```
if d_2 > d_1
    [underflow error]
d = d_2 - d_1
```

Comment: I am almost understanding it, will be continuing figuring out what things exactly mean in more of an abstract manner. Meanwhile, I should vote up some answers of yours that I find for good and enlightening.